# Запуск браузера в фоне и выполнение сценария

Tags: linux, браузер

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как в Linux запустить браузер (например, Firefox) в фоновом режиме и выполнить несколько нажатий на сайте автоматически?

Comment: посмотрите в сторону headless режима. думаю это то что вы ищите.

Comment: Selenium — ключевое слово.

Answer (score 2):

А не проще ли Вам обратить внимание на системы тестирования сайтов? К примеру, как вариант, можно попробовать [Selenium](http://www.seleniumhq.org/). Она записывает Ваши действия, после чего позволяет их проигрывать многократно.

Answer (score -1):

Что бы запустить любую программу (в Linux) в фоновом режиме, надо в конце командной строки поставить знак & Например так:

```
ls -l &
```

Но сама по себе идея запустить графическое приложение в фоновом режиме вызывает у меня некоторое изумление. Впрочем - дело Ваше.

Если Вы запускаете графическое приложение, то моделировать ввод с клавиатуры можно, к примеру, с помощью утилиты *xdotool*

Comment: Насчёт xdotool отдельное спасибо)